# source command didn't export variables to the zsh environment using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a really simple shell script which work really well on bash and export the varialbes to the current bash enviornment but unfortunately it didn't export the variables to the zsh enviornment.

```
#!/bin/bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $RESULT | jq --raw-output .Credentials.AccessKeyId)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $RESULT | jq --raw-output .Credentials.SecretAccessKey)
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=$(echo $RESULT | jq --raw-output .Credentials.SessionToken)
```

and I am running this script like this:

```
source myscript.sh
```

OR

```
. ./myscript.sh
```

Please advise, that how I can make it work on the zsh environment?

Comment: Sourcing a file in a shell environment will run sourcing file in the current shell process. So the `$RESULT` variable may probably be empty. Where do `$RESULT` come from?

Comment: $RESULT variable is not empty, I have echo it, here is the command from where the value of RESULT came:  RESULT=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$ROLE_ARN" --role-session-name "$(date +"%s")_$USER@$(hostname)" --token-code $MFA_TOKEN --serial-number $AWS_MFA_ARN)

Comment: Hmm. Zsh is more like ksh while bash is a superset of bsh. There would be some incompatible commands in the bash script that zsh can not execute. You can set XTRACE and VERBOSE options using `setopt XTRACE VERBOSE` in the zsh environment for debugging. @arbabnazar

Comment: _how I can make it work on the zsh environment?_ : What makes you think it wouldn't work? You did not show what effect you expect, and what effect you are actually see. BTW, the #! line is unneeded here, since you are sourcing the script anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the code you have posted.

Are your variables simply not defined, or are they defined and not exported, in the sourcing script?

I would turn on `set -x` before sourcing, and analyze the output. Maybe you have some commands in your sourced script, where the behaviour differs between bash and zsh. From the three lines you have posted, I don't see any incompatibilities though.